# How to apply d3.zoom() to a HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I can't figure out how to properly apply the `d3.zoom` behaviour to an HTML element (not SVG). In the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom-transforms) the only advice on how to do this is this:

> Similarly, to apply the transformation to HTML elements via CSS:

```
div.style("transform", "translate(" + transform.x + "px," + transform.y + "px) scale(" + transform.k + ")");
```

So what I did was this: (["Working" example](https://jsbin.com/mibifafudo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output))

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0.1, 1])
  .on('zoom', zoomed);

var root = d3.select('.root').call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
  var transform = d3.event.transform;
  root.style("transform", "translate(" + transform.x + "px," + transform.y + "px) scale(" + transform.k + ")");
}
```

The problem here is that, if you zoom out, the zoom will eventually stop because the mouse is not inside the zoomable area anymore.

So what I did was using a parent element to attach the zoom behaviour and a child element that gets transformed. [Here's an example](https://jsbin.com/hoqacatowo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output) of that. The problem now is that the transforms are messed up. I cannot fully comprehend what exactly is messed up and why but if I zoom with the mouse wheel, the transformed canvas is definitely not doing what it should (moving away from the mouse instead of towards it when zooming in etc.).

Unfortunately I couldn't find any example of how to use `d3.zoom` with HTML. Is there a better way to do this? Or can I somehow fix the transform when using a child element?

Answer (score 1):

Only change the `scale` value,

```
canvas.style("transform", "translate(0,0) scale(" + transform.k + ")");
```

[Working demo](https://jsbin.com/zugebibifo)

Comment: Hey!Yes that kind of works. But what if the content overlaps the inner div? Meaning has a negative position or a position that is bigger than its size? Then it is not possible to zoom towards it. [Working Demo](https://jsbin.com/sumeripako/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the scenario, but... have you tried commenting the line `.scaleExtent([0.1, 1])`? [example](https://jsbin.com/jubahomuve/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: What I mean is for example, how would I zoom in on the outer left rectangle? This rectangle is only visible if I zoom out far enough but as soon as I zoom in again it obviously goes outside the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Set the transform origin to 0,0:

```
root.style("transform", "translate(" + transform.x + "px," + transform.y + "px) scale(" + transform.k + ")").style("transform-origin","0 0");
```